# how to call jsp to java without call controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

**I am using spring mvc with hibernate connction,now how to call jsp page to java page without call controller?? i am getting error**

JSP page:

This below one is jsp page...i am using java code below but unable to get values in java class!!

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="com.sample.utility.AutoIncrement"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>check page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        AutoIncrement au=new AutoIncrement();
        String val = au.auto("ShopInfo");
        System.out.println(" val : " + val);
    %>
    <div id="login_form">
        <form:form action="check" method="post">
            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td class="f1_label">Shop code :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="shopcode" value="<%=val%>"
                        readonly /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="f1_label">name :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="login" value="Submit"
                        style="font-size: 18px;" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JAVA PAGE:

```
@Repository
public class AutoIncrement {
     @Autowired
     private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
     Query query;

     @Transactional
    public String auto(String value) {
        String reVal = "";
        System.out.println("Inc val : " + value);
        System.out.println("sessionFactory : "+sessionFactory);
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        System.out.println("session : "+session);
        try {
            System.out.println("Inside try block");
            session.beginTransaction().begin();
            String SQL_QUERY = "{CALL pro_autoincrement('" + value + "') }";            
            reVal = (String) session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY).uniqueResult();
            System.out.println("Inc val try: " + reVal);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception AutoIncrement :" + ex);
            if (session.getTransaction().getStatus() == TransactionStatus.ACTIVE
                    || session.getTransaction().getStatus() == TransactionStatus.MARKED_ROLLBACK) {
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        System.out.println("return val : " + reVal);
        return reVal;
    }
```

Error:
this one error page  while i am execute the jsp page

```
sessionFactory : null
Nov 18, 2017 12:12:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/annotation-based] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sample.utility.AutoIncrement.auto(AutoIncrement.java:29)
    at org.apache.jsp.welcome_jsp._jspService(welcome_jsp.java:83)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>storeInformation1.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
  <!-- Spring MVC dispatcher servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servelet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"></property>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        id="sessionFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.sample.entity.Shop</value>
                <value>com.sample.entity.sample</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}  </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager"
        id="hibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="language" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

</beans>
```

Comment: Your service SessionFactory is not in the application context. What are the content of your sprinklr configuration file? Which describes component-scan for the the package of SessionFactory (If it is having "@Service") or bean definition for the same?

Comment: i add spring context in web.xml

Comment: can you share the web.xml

Comment: ok..pls see above!!

Comment: and the content in `/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml` defines SessionFactory bean?

Comment: SessionFactory is having dispatcher-servlet.xml!!

Comment: The whole point of MVC is that you should never, ever execute a view without going through a controller. You're also creating Spring beans using `new`, which defeats the wole purpose of dependency injection and AOP. Use the frameworks as it's supposed to be used.

Comment: ok thanks..............